# Problem when loading routes from DB dynamically in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, browser-refresh, dynamic-routing

please help with a problem I have. I'm loading routes from a DB through a web service and everything work as expected when using links to those routes. But when I refresh the page or I write directly the url in the adress bar the route does not work, why?

on refresh browser, i am getting URL not found issue

Please help me on this issue.

1. I tried to comment our base href='/' in index.html so that it will not redirect to root
2. i tried to hold control till api response using async/await so that routecollection created first then controll will move forward for navigation

but unable to fix this issue.

i have added my code in the "app.component.ts" constructor. I call a function that loads the routes

```
   async getdynamicroutes1(){
  const config = this.router.config;
   await this.rest.fetchinpromise('Religious/GetRoutesCollection').then(data => {
        var indexData = data;
        indexData.forEach(element => {
          let url : string = `${element.EName.toLowerCase()}/:id`;
          config.push({path: url, component: ChaptersComponent, runGuardsAndResolvers:"always"});

          element.ReligiousBooks.forEach(religiousbook => {
            religiousbook.Chapters.forEach(chapter => {
              url = `${element.EName.toLowerCase()}/${this.removeSpace(religiousbook.EName)}/${this.removeSpace(chapter.EName)}/:id`;
              config.push({path:url, component: HomeDetailsComponent, runGuardsAndResolvers:"always"});
            });
          })
      });
      config.push({ path: "app/pagenotfound", component: PagenotfoundComponent })
      config.push({ path: "**", redirectTo: "app/pagenotfound", pathMatch: "full" } )
      this.router.resetConfig(config);
    },
    error => {
      console.log("Error :: " + error);
    });

}
```

on refresh browser, same page should load successfully.

Comment: I don't think this is the right approach to having dynamic routes. You should use route parameters. By subscribing to `ActivatedRoute.paramMap` you can then find out which book is requested and fetch its details from the API or whatever.

Comment: if you are using single-page-applications you might find a common error that is solvable by using HashLocationStrategy. `imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })]`, this adds a Hash behind your route though. Can you try this and tell me if it fixes it?

Comment: I tried using HashLocationStrategy, but it doesn't fixed this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But when I refresh the page or I write directly the url in the adress bar the route does not work, why?

There are no additional routes in your application yet. You would have to try to load them on boot time before application is fully started.

You can try to use APP_INITIALIZER  (https://hackernoon.com/hook-into-angular-initialization-process-add41a6b7e) or you will have to expose public variable before angular script loads the application, and append required enties directly in routing configuration.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This issue has been resolved by using APP_INITIALIZER